# Importing Objective C library in Swift Error

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to import https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder in my swift project. I added SCRecoder.xcodeproj to my project and added

```
#import <SCRecoder/SCRecoder.h>
```

in my bridging header but it gives me an error

> SCRecoder/SCRecoder.h file not found

then I tried

```
On the SCRecorder project:

    Set Build Settings > Packaging > Public Headers Folder Path to include/$(TARGET_NAME)
    Add SCRecordSession to Build Phases > Headers > Public
    Move Project headers to Public headers
```

But still same error, any idea on what I did wrong? or the correct way to do it?

Comment: Does your project name contain spaces?

Comment: no, I simply named it as "SCRecoderSwift"

Comment: build setting add path of bridging-header file

Comment: yes, it is already added,

Comment: go build setting -> Swift Compiler - code Generation -> Objective C Bridging header -> add path of projectname-bridging-header.h file i hope it works

Comment: yes the path is correct

Comment: delete SCRecoder.xcodeproj file and simply add all .h and .m files in SCRecoder

Comment: and what about all the frameworks?

Comment: @Memon thanks that worked, had to convert all objC example file to swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79338/discussion-between-ankit-and-memon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete SCRecoder.xcodeproj file and simply add all .h,.m files and frameworks in SCRecoder

Answer (score 0):

The correct (in my opinion) and easy way to do it is by using Cocoapods.
When adding the library with drag and drop make sure you are selection "copy if needed".

With Cocoapods installed , just edit the file adding "pod 'SCRecorder', '~> 2.4'" and install.